# How to combine two variances of Simpson's diversity index?

Tags: variance, diversity

I know how to combine two common variances with mean and sample size.
However, I don't know how to combine two variances if a variance has a special form.
From Simpson's diversity index, he proposed a variance equation as shown below:
$$
s^2=4[P_i^3-(P_i^2)^2]/N
$$
where $P_i$ is the proportion of the number of organisms in the $i$th species ($n_i$) to the total number of organisms in the sample $N$. Therefore, $P_i=n_i/N$.

The problem is that a new indicator developed by myself uses two elements which are from each Simpson's diversity index.  Accordingly, to get the variance of this new indicator, I need to combine two variances from each Simpson's diversity index.

How can I combine these two different variances from the above equation for each?

Comment: What do you mean by "variance" (i.e. $<x - <x>>^2$ )? and what is $s^2$? (Simpson index is $\sum_i p_i^2$.)

Comment: @PiotrMigdal yes the variance means the variability in the data I collected (the more variable the data, the greater the difference in the diversity values has to be to show a significant difference between any two Simpson't diversity index.) s^2 means the formula of variance of Simpson's index.